# Laravel - How to pass request data in anonymous function inside where

Tags: php, laravel, request, eloquent

So I want to get all items if the user hasn't selected any options, otherwise query the items according to the request data. However I can't pass the `$request` to my function. Here is my code:

```
public function showProducts(Request $request) 
{
       $products = Product::all();
       if(count($request->all()) != 0) {
                $products = Product::where(function($query) {
                    $minPrice = $request['min'] ? $request['min'] : null;
                    $maxPrice = $request['max'] ? $request['max'] : null;
                    $colors = $request['color'] ? $request['color'] : null;
                    $sizes = $request['size'] ? $request['size'] : null;

                    if($minPrice != null && $maxPrice != null) {
                        $query->where('price', '>=', $minPrice)->where('price', '<=', $maxPrice);
                    }

                    if($minPrice == null && $maxPrice == null && $colors == null && $sizes == null)  {

                    }
                })->get();
            }
}
```

Obviously I have $request in my showProducts closure however I can't access it inside my anonymous function inside `where`. How can I use my $request data in the anonymous function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword to pass in parameters from the parent scope:

```
$products = Product::where(function($query) use ($request) {
    // $request is now available
```

Now `$request` is available in your closure.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-200

Comment: Worked like a charm. Didn't know I have to use use to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I couldn't find it anywhere in Laravel documentation, but finally thanks to you, I'm saved.